Getting "Configuration is not authorized" error while deploying GCP Vertex AI Agent on App Engine
I am building a search app using GCP Vertex AI Agent Builder and trying to deploy that on App Engine.
This is my Vertex AI search app.

This is Vertex AI app datastore

This is my App Engine code:
main.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def root():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)), debug=True)

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TTC Intranet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TTC Intranet Search</h1>
    <!-- Widget JavaScript bundle -->
    <script src="https://cloud.google.com/ai/gen-app-builder/client?hl=en_US"></script>

    <!-- Search widget element is not visible by default -->
    <gen-search-widget
      configId="21a52013-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx80a5xxxx"
      triggerId="searchWidgetTrigger">
    </gen-search-widget>

    <!-- Element that opens the widget on click. It does not have to be an input -->
    <input placeholder="Search here" id="searchWidgetTrigger" />
  </body>
</html>

app.yaml
runtime: python39

The app is starting and upon clicking "search here" icon, it is redirecting to search agent page. But then it is giving below error.

Configuration is not authorized on "***.uc.r.appspot.com"


You must configure the authorized domains/subdomains under the Vertex Agent Builder Application in order for this to work.

In your case you would add the xxxx.xx.r.appspot.com (and any other domains you're using) to the authorized list.

Hi @Nick, I'm not using any dedicated domain, rather it's default url generated by app engine "https://.uc.r.appspot.com" and on integration page I'm giving Public Access. I followed medium article : https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-vertex-ai-search-to-create-a-search-widget-within-our-webapp-based-on-our-pdf-files-798cc9545d1b

yes, you have to copy the app engine domain into the allowed domains section.
